# Rewrite permalink for multiple post types (CPT) with taxonomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I need your help. I need to create a similar structure mentioned on this thread and below are the details of my project requirement:

I have three custom post types, let's say company-directory, video and articles. Each share a common taxonomy, let's call it tax.

The way I want to set up the URL is:

"tax_term" is the term name that belongs to the common taxonomy.

Company Directory stores info for company profiles. This will have the default URL, i.e. site.com/company-directory

For CPT "video" - I would want the URL to be site.com/company-directory/tax_term/video/post_slug

For CPT "articles" - site.com/company-directory/tax_term/articles/post_slug

I tried the [exact solution @RachelCarden provided](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61105/nested-custom-post-types-with-permalinks#) and it works with CPT "video" but CPT "article" is redirecting to homepage (301). Below is the code I'm working on:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_website_add_rewrite_tag' );
function my_website_add_rewrite_tag() {
//Matching the url with the custom structure
//Custom URL for videos
add_rewrite_rule( '^company-directory/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?company-video=$matches[3]','top' );
//Custom URL for reports
add_rewrite_rule( '^company-directory/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?report-presentation=$matches[2]','top' );
}

// this filter runs whenever WordPress requests a post permalink, i.e. 
get_permalink(), etc.
// we will return our custom permalink for 'videos' and 'reports'. 
//'company-directory' is already good to go since we defined its rewrite slug in the CPT definition.
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_website_filter_post_type_link', 1, 4 );
function my_website_filter_post_type_link( $post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample ) {

switch( $post->post_type ) {

    case 'company-video':

        if ( $term = array_shift( wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'trading-symbol' ) ) ) {
            if ( isset( $term->slug ) ) {
                // create the new permalink
                $post_link = home_url( user_trailingslashit( 'company-directory/' . $term->slug . '/videos/' . $post->post_name ) );
            }
        }

    break;

    case 'report-presentation':

    if ( $term2 = array_shift( wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'trading-symbol' ) ) ) {

        if ( isset( $term2->slug ) ) {
            // create the new permalink
            $post_link = home_url( user_trailingslashit( 'company-directory/' .$term2->slug. '-report-presentation/' . $post->post_name ) );
        }

    }
        break;

}
return $post_link;
```

}

I was hoping someone could guide me on solving this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK so after scratching my head for a day, I decided to rewrite the function. After searching for few minutes, I came across [this tutorial](http://www.ibenic.com/custom-wordpress-rewrite-rule-combine-taxonomy-post-type/) that outlined the solution for me. It works like a charm. I hope it helps you guys too.